# httpcontextaccessor null reference on app service but not debug

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor

I have a weird issue I can't explain.

I have a helper class in my Blazor Server Side app that does arb functions for my app.  I added  `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in startup,

declared it in my helper class

```
public GlobalHelper(IHttpContextAccessor accessor, 
            IOptions<AzureADB2COptions> azureAdB2COptions,
            IConfiguration configuration
            
           )
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
            AzureAdB2COptions = azureAdB2COptions.Value;
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }
```

and then have a function to return the userid:

```
 public string GetUserID()
    {
        var context = _accessor.HttpContext;


        return context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

and then in my page, I just want to display it first on a button click event:

```
 @inject Classes.GlobalHelper _helper

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>


@code {

    string currentCount = "test";

    void IncrementCount()
    {
        var test4 = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        var authState = AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
        var user = authState.Result.User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {

            try
            {
            

                currentCount = _helper.GetUserID().Result;
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                currentCount = ex.ToString();
            }


        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The user is NOT authenticated.");
        }


    }
}
```

If I just debug locally, this works fine.  As soon as I publish this to an app service in Azure... I get a `nullreferenceexception` on accessing the `httpcontextaccessor` in the globalhelper class. This line:

```
return context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

What could I be doing wrong so that the httpcontext is null in the app service and not in debug on my local machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpContext` is not available, at least most of the time, in Blazor Server App. You shouldn't try to access it, and you shouldn't use `IHttpContextAccessor`. Read more here:
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14090
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13903
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12432#issuecomment-534315513
https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5330#issuecomment-413928731

Note: You may access Authentication State in Blazor Server App via the `AuthenticationStateProvider` object and authorization components such as `AuthorizeView`, `AuthorizeRouteView` and `CascadingAuthenticationState` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Fair enough, I'd prefer to use AuthStateProvider, but I haven't found a way to use authstateprovider in a custom class.  It seems that authstateprovider is quite hard to use in DI.  My App do have a requirement to use authstate outside of views (for example, my custom helper class) at times.  It's also recommended not to use authstateprovider directly, so I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place...

Comment: Thanks for the links.  So I guess the question is, what's the best way of keeping vars in blazor server side.  Local storage?

Comment: This is whack. Why make the stuff work when VisualStudio is running it if it will not work in a published environment? It's so frustrating.